# Run scipt from URL in Magento

Tags: magento-1.8

I have a script that I want to execute directly from URL like www.websitename.com/myscript.php. How can I do that? When I try to run my script i get 404 site. Is there any other way I could execute this script?

Comment: make sure the file exists on the same level as index.php

Comment: make sure myscript.php exists at the same level at which your app,skin folders lies.

Comment: I have the script inside the same folder as index.php aka in the base folder of my Magento installation.

Comment: please confirm your script exist in root magento setup if it exist check your htaccess or place your htacces here